# Bounding a difference of square roots

Tags: inequality, roots, absolute-value

I have two quantities which came from solving quadratic equations: $\frac{n+1+\sqrt{28n^2+20n-71}}{9}$ and $\frac{n+3+\sqrt{28n^2-12n+9}}{9}$. I can see that in the limit as $n \to \infty$ they approach the same value: $\frac{1+2\sqrt{7}}{9} \cdot n$. These two quantities are in fact very close together, graphically it looks like their difference is less than 1 in absolute value for $n \ge 2$. How can I show that?

Manipulating *equations* involving square roots is already tricky, but attempting those same techniques here only seems to work at proving the upper bound, namely: $$\frac{n+1+\sqrt{28n^2+20n-71}}{9} - \frac{n+3+\sqrt{28n^2-12n+9}}{9} \le 1$$ When $n \ge$ 1.8ish. How would you show the lower bound of -1 when $n \ge 2$?

Comment: I suppose a typo somewhere since, when $n \to \infty$, both expressions approach $\frac{1+2\sqrt{7}}{9}\color{red}{n}$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
\begin{align}
\Delta &=\frac{n+1+\sqrt{28n^2+20n-71}}{9} - \frac{n+3+\sqrt{28n^2-12n+9}}{9}\\
& = -\frac{2}{9}+\frac{\sqrt{28n^2+20n-71}-\sqrt{28n^2-12n+9}}{9} \\
& = -\frac{2}{9}+\frac{28n^2+20n-71-28n^2+12n-9}{9(\sqrt{28n^2+20n-71}+\sqrt{28n^2-12n+9})}\\
& = -\frac{2}{9}+\underbrace{\frac{32n-80}{9(\sqrt{28n^2+20n-71}+\sqrt{28n^2-12n+9})}}_{\text{increasing function of } n}\\
& \ge -\frac{2}{9}+{\frac{32(2)-80}{9(\sqrt{28(2)^2+20(2)-71}+\sqrt{28(2)^2-12(2)+9})}}\\
& \ge -\frac{2}{9}-\frac{16}{9(9+\sqrt{97})}\\
& \ge -1.
\end{align}

Comment: How do you know that that crazy function of n is increasing?